# Inserting a function in Webpack Plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-file-loader

Does anyone know how to insert and reuse a function in a Webpack plugin? Like from my plugin insert that function `myFunction()` and call it from the generated bundle?

Background information:

I'm replacing some paths to some assets that are inside other libraries.

- Library A uses file1.afm to file14.afm
- Library B uses file1.trie to file4.trie

I put these files in my package using `file-loader` and then I require each file:

```
const f1 = require('file1.afm')
```

And so forth for every single file.

But Library A and B are doing something like the following:

```
data = base64.toByteArray(fs.readFileSync('../src/js/somePath/inLibrary/Private/file1.afm', 'base64'));
```

For every single file. I want to replace that path with the correct path to the bundle, but the `__dirname` doesn't help. That's why I want to use [callsites](https://github.com/sindresorhus/callsites).

What I want to do is insert [callsites](https://github.com/sindresorhus/callsites) as a global dependency on my bundle and use it similarly to `__webpack_require__(moduleId)` so that I can pull in the executing js file path (`__dirname` or `__filename` don't work)

So in theory I would insert `callsites()[0].getFileName() + __webpack_require__(moduleId)`

So far my config looks like this, and `webpack-file-resolver` is the current plugin i'm doing:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpackTs = require('webpack-config-typescript')
var WebpackFileResolver = require('webpack-file-resolver')


let config = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src/handler.ts'),
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    filename: 'deploy/handler_[hash].js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    path: path.join(__dirname)
  }
}

config = webpackTs.ts(config)
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.(ttf|trie|afm)$/,
  loader: "file-loader",
  options: {
    name: "[name].[ext]",
    outputPath: "deploy",
    publicPath: "./"
  },
})

config.plugins.push(new WebpackFileResolver({
  test: /\.(trie|afm)$/,
  serverPath: "./"
}))

module.exports = config
```

So far this is what I got:

```
const ConcatSource = require("webpack-sources").ConcatSource

function getRequires (options, chunks) {
  return chunks.reduce((c, chunk) => {
    chunk.forEachModule((module) => {
      const deps = module && module.fileDependencies && module.fileDependencies || []
      deps.forEach((filepath) => {
        if(options.test.test(filepath)) {
          c.add({
            path: filepath,
            id: module.id
          })
        }
      })
    })
    return c
  }, new Set())
}

class WebpackFileResolverPlugin {
  constructor(options = {}) {
    this.options = options
  }

  apply(compiler) {
    const options = this.options
    compiler.plugin('compilation', (compilation) => {
      compilation.plugin('optimize-chunk-assets',  (chunks, done) => {
        const requires = getRequires(options, chunks)
        replaceBundleReadDir(compilation, chunks, requires)
        done()
      })
    })
  }
}

function replaceBundleReadDir(compilation, chunks, requires){
    chunks.forEach(function (chunk) {
        chunk.files.forEach(function (fileName) {
            replaceSource(compilation, fileName, requires)
        })
    })
}

function replaceSource(compilation, fileName, requires){
    let result = compilation.assets[fileName].source()
  const source = []
    requires.forEach((require) => {
    let buffer = []
    for (let c of result) {
      if (c !== '\n') {
        buffer.push(c)
      } else {
        const line = buffer.join('')
        const newLine = replaceFsReadDir (require, line)
        if (newLine !== undefined) {
          result = result.replace(line, newLine)
        }
        buffer = []
      }
    }
    })
    compilation.assets[fileName] = new ConcatSource(result)
}

function replaceFsReadDir (require, line) {
  const webpackRequire = '__webpack_require__'
  const fileName = require.path.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
  const fileStartMarker = line.indexOf(fileName)
  const readDirMarker = line.lastIndexOf('readFile')
  if (fileStartMarker !== -1 && readDirMarker !== -1) {
    let fileEndMarker = line.indexOf(')', fileStartMarker)
    let getEnd = line.slice(fileStartMarker, fileEndMarker + 1)
    fileEndMarker = (getEnd.length > fileName.length + 2) ? line.indexOf(',', fileStartMarker) : fileEndMarker
    const startSlice = line.indexOf('(', readDirMarker) + 1
    const newLine = `${line.slice(0, startSlice)}${webpackRequire}(${require.id})${line.slice(fileEndMarker)}`
    return newLine
  } else {
    return undefined
  }
}

module.exports = WebpackFileResolverPlugin
```

Comment: "I put these files in my package using file-loader, but the paths in both Library A and B are relative to their source, which breaks when bundled." Why not `import` them, which would solve the path issue?

Comment: They're imported in my codebase (that's how they get to the bundle). It doesn't solve the issue that both libraries will try to readFile for their paths in their source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I'll use the following, it's very hacky so I can't really recommend it.

What I do is I prepend my global functions to my bundle, then replace the paths with path to the current executing javascript. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
const ConcatSource = require("webpack-sources").ConcatSource

// This is the function I want to use on my bundle
const noRestForTheWicked = `
const __callsites__ = () => {
    const _ = Error.prepareStackTrace;
    Error.prepareStackTrace = (_, stack) => stack;
    const stack = new Error().stack.slice(1);
    Error.prepareStackTrace = _;
    return stack;
}
const __current_file__ = () => {
  const sep = require('path').sep
  let filePieces = __callsites__()[0].getFileName().split(sep)
  return filePieces.slice(0, -1).join(sep) + sep
};

`

function getRequires (options, chunks) {
  return chunks.reduce((c, chunk) => {
    chunk.forEachModule((module) => {
      const deps = module && module.fileDependencies && module.fileDependencies || []
      deps.forEach((filepath) => {
        if(options.test.test(filepath)) {
          c.add({
            path: filepath,
            id: module.id
          })
        }
      })
    })
    return c
  }, new Set())
}

class WebpackFileResolverPlugin {
  constructor(options = {}) {
    this.options = options
  }

  apply(compiler) {
    const options = this.options
    compiler.plugin('compilation', (compilation) => {
      compilation.plugin('optimize-chunk-assets',  (chunks, done) => {
        const requires = getRequires(options, chunks)
        replaceBundleReadDir(compilation, chunks, requires, options)
        done()
      })
    })
  }
}

function replaceBundleReadDir(compilation, chunks, requires, options){
    chunks.forEach(function (chunk) {
        chunk.files.forEach(function (fileName) {
            replaceSource(compilation, fileName, requires, options)
        })
    })
}

function replaceSource(compilation, fileName, requires, options){
    let result = compilation.assets[fileName].source()
  if ('serverPath' in options && options.serverPath !== undefined) {
     // This is where the hacking happens
     result = noRestForTheWicked + result
  }
    requires.forEach((require) => {
    let buffer = []
    for (let c of result) {
      if (c !== '\n') {
        buffer.push(c)
      } else {
        const line = buffer.join('')
        const newLine = replaceFsReadDir (require, line, options)
        if (newLine !== undefined) {
          result = result.replace(line, newLine)
        }
        buffer = []
      }
    }
    })
    compilation.assets[fileName] = new ConcatSource(result)
}

function replaceFsReadDir (require, line, options) {
  const webpackRequire = '__webpack_require__'
  const fileName = require.path.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
  const fileStartMarker = line.indexOf(fileName)
  const readDirMarker = line.lastIndexOf('readFile')
  if (fileStartMarker !== -1 && readDirMarker !== -1) {
    let fileEndMarker = line.indexOf(')', fileStartMarker)
    let getEnd = line.slice(fileStartMarker, fileEndMarker + 1)
    fileEndMarker = (getEnd.length > fileName.length + 2) ? line.indexOf(',', fileStartMarker) : fileEndMarker
    const startSlice = line.indexOf('(', readDirMarker) + 1
    let importStr = `${webpackRequire}(${require.id})`
    if ('serverPath' in options && options.serverPath !== undefined) {
      // Server Land, brace for impact, inserting the thing
      importStr = `__current_file__() + ${importStr}`
    }
    const newLine = `${line.slice(0, startSlice)}${importStr}${line.slice(fileEndMarker)}`
    return newLine
  } else {
    return undefined
  }
}

module.exports = WebpackFileResolverPlugin
```